# Database query select all columns including count with every record by 'group by'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, hql

Use Criteria or HQL(Hibernate Query Language), select **all columns**. **Grouping by** any one column of selected columns and also select **count** with every record for which we use **group by**.

Sample SQL Query ex: **select *,count(1) from users group by name**

Answer (score 0):

Have you try run that SQL of yours? you can't run this query right?

```
select *,count(1) from users group by name
```

you will recheive some error like:

```
Column 'some_column_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

what you can is query something like this:

```
select name, count(name) from users group by name
```

In this case you can use projection in your criteria to count with group by, something like :

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("name"))
    .add(Projections.count("name")));
```